# Variable Value as Range

Tags: output-formatting, variable-definitions

Thank you for the help so far!

I would like to assign +/i signs for the function and solution such as (+)(+)(-) and therefore (-).

It is working for the first evaluation, λlower, but not for the second evaluation, λupper. I cannot see the difference - has it to do with "λi /. Solve" in both definitions?

```
    (* Endogenous *)
    Clear[μ, ξ, β, γ, ri, si, rj, sj, λCri, λCsi , λlower, λupper, λlowereip, λip];
    (* Exogenous *)
    Clear[ ci, yp, λi, αi, ϵip, ηip, eip];
    ri = ϵip*λi + (1 - ηip)*(1 - λi);
    si = ηip*(1 - λi) + (1 - ϵip)*λi; 
    λCri = (ϵip*λi)/(ϵip*λi + (1 - ηip)*(1 - λi));
    λCsi = (ηip*(1 - λi))/(ηip*(1 - λi) + (1 - ϵip)*λi);
    λlower = λi /. 
    Solve[ri*(yp - eip - ci + αi*λCri) + si*(yp - eip + αi*(1 - λCsi)) == yp + αi*(1 - λi), {λi}];
    λupper = λi /.Solve[ri*(yp - eip - ci + αi*λCri) + 
  si*(yp - eip + αi*(1 - λCsi)) == yp + αi*λi - ci, {λi} ];
    Simplify[D[λlower, eip]]
    Simplify[Sign[D[λlower, eip]], αi > 0 && eip > 0 && ci > 0 && 0 < ϵip < 1 && 0 < ci < 1 && 0 < ηip < 1 && αi > ci && αi > ci + eip && ϵip + ηi < 1]
    Simplify[D[λupper, eip]]
    Simplify[Sign[D[λupper, eip]], αi > 0 && eip > 0 && ci > 0 && 0 < ϵip < 1 && 0 < ci < 1 && 0 < ηip < 1 && αi > ci && αi > ci + eip && ϵip + ηi < 1]
```

Comment: Mathematica supports intervals, a = Interval[{0, 1}] and Assuming[0<a<1,Simplify[...]] Perhaps you can use one or both of those and see if you can get where you want to go, BUT in my experience it sometimes doesn't propagate through a chain of statements to give what you can sometimes see the answer should be.

Comment: `Simplify[Sign[a (1 - b) (1 - a - b)], 0 < a < 1 && 0 < b < 1 && a + b > 1]`?

Comment: If I use 

    `\[Lambda]lowereip = Simplify[D[\[Lambda]lower, eip]]
    Simplify[Sign[\[Lambda]lowereip],  0 < \[Epsilon]ip < 1 && 0 < ci < 1 && 0 < \[Eta]ip < 1 && \[Alpha]i > ci && \[Alpha]i > ci + eip && \[Epsilon]ip + \[Eta]i < 1]`

, then I get only {{0 -> ...}}

However, if I use the value of \[Lambda]lowereip and copy it and define it as "x" 

    `x = 1/(2 \[Alpha]i - ci (-1 + \[Epsilon]ip + \[Eta]ip))
    Simplify[Sign[x], 0 < \[Epsilon]ip < 1 && 0 < ci < 1 && 
  0 < \[Eta]ip < 1 && \[Alpha]i > ci && \[Alpha]i > 
   ci + eip && \[Epsilon]ip + \[Eta]i < 1]`

it is working.

Comment: @TomG: I tried evaluating `\[Lambda]lowereip = 
 Simplify[D[\[Lambda]lower, eip]] Simplify[Sign[\[Lambda]lowereip], 
   0 < \[Epsilon]ip < 1 && 0 < ci < 1 && 
    0 < \[Eta]ip < 1 && \[Alpha]i > ci && \[Alpha]i > 
     ci + eip && \[Epsilon]ip + \[Eta]i < 1]` which produces `0`. That's because you forgot to post the relevant parts of your code, and we can't help you if you forget to post the code that your question is about. :) Also, note that kguler's suggestion solves the question as you asked it, so unless we're missing something, your question appears to be answered.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus: I have updated the question with the example code.

Comment: Tom, if you use `\[Lambda]lower = \[Lambda]i /. Solve[ri*(yp - eip - ci + \[Alpha]i*\[Lambda]Cri) +  si*(yp - eip + \[Alpha]i*(1 - \[Lambda]Csi)) ==  yp + \[Alpha]i*(1 - \[Lambda]i), {\[Lambda]i}]`, then `Simplify[Sign[\[Lambda]lowereip],...]` works.

Comment: It's working. Great!

Comment: It is working for one variable (with various derivatives) but not for another variable (and its derivatives).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
exp = {Sign[a], Sign[1 - b], Sign[1 - a - b], 
   Sign[a (1 - a) (1 - a - b)]};
ref = Assuming[{0 < a < 1 && Element[a, Reals] 0 < b < 1 && 
     Element[b, Reals] && a + b > 1}, Refine[exp]];
Grid[{exp, ref /. {1 -> "+", -1 -> "-"}}, 
 Dividers -> {{True, {None}, True, True}, {{True}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful for the visualization!

Answer (score 2):

```
expressions = {a, 1 - a, 1 - b, a + b, a (1 - b) (1 - a - b)};
assumptions = 0 < a < 1 && 0 < b < 1 && a + b > 1;

signF = Simplify[Sign@#, #2]  /. {1 -> "+", -1 -> "-"} &;

signF[expressions, assumptions]
(* {"+","+","+","+","-"} *)

Grid[{expressions, signF[expressions, assumptions]}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]